# Sort two lists that started from a single linked list?

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

**EDIT**: This question has not received any feedback in a few days and I would like to ask if there are any unclear parts that I could improve in the description so you could attempt answering without hesitation. Thank you.

---

The program given below, groups the input in two different tables based on the gender and should sort the data by age in descending order. See below for more explanation:

```
Insert the code of the person Number 1: 1
Insert the age of the person Number 1: 1
Insert the gender of the person Number 1: 1
Insert the code of the person Number 2: 2
Insert the age of the person Number 2: 2
Insert the gender of the person Number 2: 1
Insert the code of the person Number 3: 3
Insert the age of the person Number 3: 3
Insert the gender of the person Number 3: 1
Insert the code of the person Number 4: 4
Insert the age of the person Number 4: 2
Insert the gender of the person Number 4: 0
Insert the code of the person Number 5: 5
Insert the age of the person Number 5: 3
Insert the gender of the person Number 5: 0
```

And the result is the following:

```
Men
        Code    Age     Gender
        3       3       1
        1       1       1
        2       2       1
Women
        Code    Age     Gender
        4       2       0
        5       3       0
```

The proper result should be the following (**hint**: Sorted by Age):

```
Men
        Code    Age     Gender
         3       3       1
         2       2       1
         1       1       1
Women
        Code    Age     Gender
         5       3       0
         4       2       0
```

**-NOTES-**

The issue is probably only in the `sort_List()` function and it is needed to include the first node of two lists in a sorting function.

How can the `sortList()` be modified to work correctly?
The code is displayed below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct people
{             /* a struct for people*/
    int code; /* a unique identifier for each person*/
    int age;
    int gender;
    struct people *next;
} ppl;

ppl *make_ppl(int code, int age, int gender, ppl *next)
{
    ppl *p = malloc( sizeof(struct people) ); //as suggested in the comments
    p->code = code;
    p->age = age;
    p->gender = gender;
    p->next = next;
    return p;
}

// a function to insert nodes
void insertFirst(ppl **ppHead, int code, int age, int gender)
{
    *ppHead = make_ppl(code, age, gender, *ppHead);
}


void sortList() {  
        //Node current will point to head  
        int head;
        ppl *current = head, *index = NULL;  
        int temp;  
          
        if(head == NULL) {  
            return;  
        }  
        else {  
            while(current != NULL) {  
                //Node index will point to node next to current  
                index = current->next;  
                  
                while(index != NULL) {  
                    //If current node's data is greater than index's node data, swap the data between them  
                    if(current->age < index->age) {                       
                        temp = current-> age;  
                        current->age = index->age;  
                        index->age = temp;
                        
                        temp = current-> code;  
                        current->code = index->code;  
                        index->code = temp;  
                        
                        temp = current-> gender;  
                        current->gender = index->gender;  
                        index->gender = temp; 
                    }  
                    index = index->next;  
                }  
                current = current->next;  
            }      
        }  
    }

    

// display the list
void printList(const char *title, ppl const *head)
{
    sortList();

    static const char *myStrings[] = {"Code", "Age", "Gender"};
    static const size_t n_strings = sizeof myStrings / sizeof *myStrings;
    int i;
    puts(title);
    for (i=0; i<n_strings; ++i)
        printf("\t%s", myStrings[i]);
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    // start from the beginning
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", head->code, head->age, head->gender);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

and then the main() is below:

```
 int main()
    {
        int i;
        ppl *z1 = NULL;
        ppl *z2 = NULL;
        
        int code1, age1, gender1;
    
        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            printf("Insert the code of the person Number %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &code1);
    
            printf("Insert the age of the person Number %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &age1);
    
            printf("Insert the gender of the person Number %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &gender1);
    
            if (gender1 == 1)
                insertFirst(&z1, code1, age1, gender1); // Here it stores in z1 for men
            else
                insertFirst(&z2, code1, age1, gender1); // Here it stores in z2 for women
        }
    
        printList("Men", z1);
        printList("Women", z2);
    
   
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Actually one problem is in `make_ppl` where you have `ppl *p = malloc( sizeof *p );` - you are allocating only the size of a pointer.  You’ll need this instead : `ppl *p = malloc( sizeof(struct people) );`

Comment: Any ideas on the sorting function that will enable the proper sorting as in the example?

Comment: The sorting method looks ok to me (generally I would prefer to swap the pointers around, but swapping the values does work).   However, I see that you are calling `sortlist()` AFTER printing, so what we are seeing in the printed output has nothing to do with the sorting.    (As an aside, also the output does not match your displayed input - eg, in your input you show person 2 being entered with gender 0 female, but in the output that person has become gender 1 in the Men section. )

Comment: I have attempted putting the sortlist() function in the beginning of the print function but still does not display the needed result. When do you suggest to put the sortlist() function? The 0 you mentioned in the gender was a typo.

Comment: Pay attention to the warnings your compiler is yelling at you. `int head; ppl *current = head` What list are you sorting?

Comment: This is not correct, yes. This is mostly the part that may need fix but I cannot find the solution.

Comment: Have you ever written a function in C? Do you understand the purpose of function parameters? Look at the function `void printList(const char *title, ppl const *head)`. Do you see the parameter `ppl const *head`? That's the list you will be printing. Now look at the function `void sortList()`. Where's the list you will be sorting?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct people
{             /* a struct for people*/
    int code; /* a unique identifier for each person*/
    int age;
    int gender;
    struct people *next;
} ppl;

ppl *make_ppl(int code, int age, int gender, ppl *next)
{
    ppl *p = malloc( sizeof(struct people) );;
    p->code = code;
    p->age = age;
    p->gender = gender;
    p->next = next;
    return p;
}

// a function to insert nodes
void insertFirst(ppl **ppHead, int code, int age, int gender)
{
    *ppHead = make_ppl(code, age, gender, *ppHead);
}


void sortList(ppl *head) {  
        //Node current will point to head  
        ppl *current = head, *index = NULL;  
        int temp;  
          
        if(head == NULL) {  
            return;  
        }  
        else {  
            while(current != NULL) {  
                //Node index will point to node next to current  
                index = current->next;  
                  
                while(index != NULL) {  
                    //If current node's data is greater than index's node data, swap the data between them  
                    if(current->age < index->age) {                          
                        temp = current-> age;  
                        current->age = index->age;  
                        index->age = temp;
                        
                        temp = current-> code;  
                        current->code = index->code;  
                        index->code = temp;  
                        
                        temp = current-> gender;  
                        current->gender = index->gender;  
                        index->gender = temp; 
                        
                    
                    }  
                    index = index->next;  
                }  
                current = current->next;  
            }      
        }  
    }
    

// display the list
void printList(const char *title, ppl  *head)
{

    static const char *myStrings[] = {"Code", "Age", "Gender"};
    static const size_t n_strings = sizeof myStrings / sizeof *myStrings;
    sortList(head);

    int i;
    puts(title);
    for (i=0; i<n_strings; ++i)
        printf("\t%s", myStrings[i]);
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    // start from the beginning
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", head->code, head->age, head->gender);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

void deleteList(ppl **ppHead)
{
    while (*ppHead)
    {
        ppl *p = *ppHead;
        *ppHead = p->next;
        free(p);
    }
}

    
      
int main()
{
    int i;
    ppl *z1 = NULL;
    ppl *z2 = NULL;
    
    int code1, age1, gender1;

    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        printf("Insert the code of the person Number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &code1);

        printf("Insert the age of the person Number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &age1);

        printf("Insert the gender of the person Number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &gender1);

        if (gender1 == 1)
            insertFirst(&z1, code1, age1, gender1); // Here it stores in z1 for men
        else
            insertFirst(&z2, code1, age1, gender1); // Here it stores in z2 for women
    }

    printList("Men", z1);
    printList("Women", z2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.